# Why do straws get attracted to charged amber when they are not charged themselves?

Tags: electrostatics

Amber on rubbing with wool attracts pieces of straw. But, as I understand, the straws are thenselves uncharged, let alone oppositely charged. So how is it possible?

Comment: Polarization occurs..

Answer (score 2):

The process of rubbing amber on wool moves charges between the two materials so that one obtains a net positive charge and the other a net negative charge on their surfaces (it is irrelevant which is actually positive and which is actually negative for this question).

When you bring the charged (lets say positive) object near your straw, the molecules in the straw will reorient themselves so that the negative charges are overall closer to the positive object than the positive charges, thus leading to an attraction. This is why the straw would be attracted to either the wool or the amber. The charges in the straw opposite to whatever you bring close to it will move to be closer to that object, thus producing an attraction.

This is somewhat different from what happens in a conductor where charges can move freely throughout the conductor. In the insulating straw molecules just reorient themselves but stay in place.